# Using Chrome USB tethering to test React and NodeJS apps with Android phone. Can't connect back end

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug some errors I'm having on mobile, with a React front end (localhost:3000) with NodeJS back end (localhost:5008). I have managed to connect my android phone and run the front end on my phone browser successfully. I can also view the console on my computer.

I'm stuck on trying to get my localhost:5008 back end server connected to my phone. I've tried adding 5008 to the port settings:
[image: port forward settings]

But this doesn't seem to do anything. So I then tried clicking the *Open dedicated DevTools for Node* link. I then set up the 5008 port in there:

[image: devtools for Node set up]

This triggers infinite GET requests to `/json` and `json/version` endpoints. I'm not sure if I should set up routes to handle this, or what to return. I'm not even sure this is the correct way to allow my phone to connect to my back end server. Can anyone explain how to enable my React app to make calls to my NodeJS server through a USB-to-mobile connection?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it again and it started working. Turns out I didn't want to include my back end server on the page on the **Open dedicated DevTools for Node** link (see second image in OP). Instead, I just needed to have the back end server included in the **Port Forwarding Settings** (see second image).